# Web Api / Azure Mobile Service Failing To Send Small File in Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to send a post to my Azure mobile service with a byte array that is storing my file.  The Uploaded Post object is null on my service if the Byte Array is larger than 5mb.  I get a 500 error.

The object that is serialized is:

```
public class UserUploadRequest
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long ContainerId { get; set; }
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    public byte[] Upload { get; set; }

    public string UploadFileExtension { get; set; }

    public bool RequiresThumbnail { get; set; }

    public long? CampaignId { get; set; }
}
```

The Web Request:

```
private static U SendWebRequestPost<T, U>(T serializeThis, string apiCall)
    {
        var webAddr = WEB_SERVICE_URL + apiCall;
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, serializeThis);
        }


        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(result); ;
        }
    }
```

The Web Api Controller Method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/UserUpload")]
public class UserUploadController : ApiController
{
    public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

    [Route("Upload"), HttpPost]
    public ServiceResponse<UserUpload> Upload([FromBody] UserUploadRequest userUploadRequest)
    {
        ServiceResponse<UserUpload> response = new ServiceResponse<UserUpload>();
```

Comment: What does the body of the (500) response message say? Also, if you look at the logs tab in the Azure portal, do you see any message that could be related to this request?

Comment: The error logs indicate that the Post object is null.

There is no other information in the exception, just: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.  There is no inner exception or other information.